# Nginx 1 FastCGI sent in stderr: “Primary script unknown”

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

My first time using Nginx, but I am more than familiar with Apache and Linux. I am using an existing project and when ever I am trying to see the index.php I get a 404 File not found.

Here is the access.log entry:

```
2013/06/19 16:23:23 [error] 2216#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.ordercloud.lh"
```

And here is the sites-available file:

```
server {
    set $host_path "/home/willem/git/console/www";
    access_log  /www/logs/console-access.log  main;

    server_name  console.ordercloud;
    root   $host_path/htdocs;
    set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(protected|framework|themes/\w+/views) {
        deny  all;
    }

    #avoid processing of calls to unexisting static files by yii
    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

        #let yii catch the calls to unexising PHP files
        set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
        if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
            set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;

        #PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED can be omitted, but RFC 3875 specifies them for CGI
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

My /home/willem/git/console is owned by www-data:www-data (my web user running php etc) and I have given it 777 permissions out of frustration...

My best guess is that something is wrong with the config, but I can't figure it out...

**UPDATE**
So I moved it to `/var/www/` and used a much more basic config:

```
server {
    #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name console.ordercloud;

    location / {
        root           /var/www/console/frontend/www/;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www;
            include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
        }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Also if I call `localhost/console/frontend/www/index.php` I get a 500 PHP which means it is serving there. It just isn't serving off console.ordercloud ...

Comment: Another possible cause: If you are using php-fpm, make sure the user set in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf has permissions for the script it is trying to run. I think it defaults to apache.

Comment: Another possible cause your SElinux is enabled, checkout SElinux config and disable it.

Comment: I just switched my Host Configuration from FCGId (run as virtual server owner) to FPM (run as virtual server owner).
In addition to installing PhP 7.2-fpm, cli and more ...

Comment: For me, `include fastcgi.conf` was missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, so 3 things I found after a day of struggling

1. For some reason I had already something running on port 9000 so I
   changed to 9001
2. My default site was intercepting my new one, once again I don't
   under stand why since it shouldn't, but I just unlinked it
3. Nginx doesn't automatically do the sym link for sites-available to
   site-enabled.

Hope this saves someone some trouble!

Comment: hello @we0, I have facing same issue with my setup. I have also running my another app on port 3001, so I have to host my php app on port 3002. you can see my original post here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229867/running-both-node-js-and-php-on-nginx-on-the-same-server-on-ubuntu-14-04 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409539/nginx-shows-php-code-instead-of-executing and another is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33519989/why-php-code-shows-in-browser. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Automatically making symlinks from sites-available to sites-enabled would be, well, undesirable. It's up to you to make those symlinks so that you can control which sites are 'on' and which are 'off' on your server.

Comment: @Erathiel `s/undesirable/nonsense`. It's the main idea enable and disable them using these symlinks.

Answer (score 133):

The error message “primary script unknown” is **almost always** related to a wrongly set `SCRIPT_FILENAME` in the nginx `fastcgi_param` directive (or incorrect permissions, see other answers).

You’re using an `if` in the configuration you posted first. Well it should be well known by now that [if is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) and often produces problems.

Setting the `root` directive within a location block is bad practice, of course it works.

You could try something like the following:

```
server {
    location / {
        location ~* \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            try_files $uri @yii =404;
        }
    }
    location @yii {
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$yii_bootstrap;
    }
}
```

Please note that the above configuration is untested. You should execute `nginx -t` before applying it to check for problems that nginx can detect right away.

Comment: This solve it for me; I was not aware that you had to prefix $document_root, I assumed it did that automatically, based on root.

Comment: After upgrading system everything was broken, i found this answer and $document_root helped me too. Why my server worked properly before upgrade?

Comment: Impossible to tell without the full configuration.

Comment: I am using homestead and fastcgi_param is having the same value as you wrote, but that does not change anything and I get 403 Forbidden error

Comment: Where can one learn more about the bad practice of setting the `root` within location?

Comment: For those who don't understand exactly how the variable might be wrong: add to main Nginx `http` section the following: `log_format scripts '$document_root$fastcgi_script_name > $request';` (or whatever you're feeding to SCRIPT_FILENAME), and to your `server`: `access_log /var/log/nginx/scripts.log scripts`. Reload and take a look at your new scripts log ;)

Comment: "Setting the root directive within a location block is bad practice," false

Comment: Yeah, sure: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block

Comment: You beautiful beautiful man - 'fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;'

Comment: Note that the order of the directives matters.  `include fastcgi_params;` must occur before `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME ...`, or the include directive will override the SCRIPT_FILENAME setting with the default.

Comment: For me, the one-line fix was to add "try_files" to the php block, which I previously did not have, specifically the "=404".

Comment: Just want to echo @richardkmiller, my problem was the `try_files` was missing in both the location directive and the php_fpm directive. The solution for me was to add the `try_files` to the `location` directive and php-fpm was able to serve the pages.

Comment: Downvoted! The very first statement (especially the **bolded** word) is **false**! My `SCRIPT_FILENAME` was 100% correct. That was NOT the issue for me. For me it was a matter of differing ownership: of php-fpm vs. the script file. @william-turrel's answer is correct! This particular issue will be even more common now for all of those running vagrant.

Comment: What is the yii_bootstrap?

Comment: you save my day!

Comment: Things aren't evil, people just use them incorrectly.

Comment: In my case I had to user `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;` to solve the problem. I am using an alias inside the location.

Answer (score 74):

It's not **always** that the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is wrong.
It may also be **PHP is running as the wrong user/group**.

This example is specific to **Mac OS X**, which in my experience is the most troublesome to setup (Debian is easy by comparison) - I've just upgraded from PHP 5.6 to 7.0, using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and the excellent josegonzalez packages.

The problem was that a new copy of the config files was created.

The main config file is `/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.conf`, but note the  **Pool Definitions** section at the end where it includes a whole subdirectory.

`include=/usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.d/*.conf`

In `php-fpm.d` there's a `www.conf` file. By default this has:

```
user = _www
group = _www
```

On OS X, you may need to change this to:

```
user = [your username]
group = staff
```

(you should find this matches an `ls -lh` of your document_root)

Unfortunately without this change, you will still see this in your Nginx error log **even if it's looking for the file in the correct place**.

```
"Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream
```

**Verify what it's currently running as:**

```
ps aux | grep 'php-fpm'
```

or more cleanly:

```
ps aux | grep -v root | grep php-fpm | cut -d\  -f1 | sort | uniq
```

**How to verify if the script filename is correct:**

(stolen from igorsantos07 in the other answer)

Add to `http` block of main `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
log_format scripts '$document_root$fastcgi_script_name > $request';
```

(where the first bit needs to be whatever you're currently using, so you can see if it's right.)

And to use the log you've just defined, in your site's `server` block:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/scripts.log scripts;
```

If it's correct, requesting example.com/phpinfo.php will produce something like this:

```
/path/to/docroot/phpinfo.php > GET /phpinfo.php
```

**Can you simplify your existing config?**

Are you using a `location ~ \.php {` block you copied/pasted from somewhere off the internet? Most packages allow you to do it more quickly and cleanly. e.g. on OS X you now just need this:

```
location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # any site specific settings, e.g. environment variables
}
```

Things like fastcgi_split_path_info, try_files and fastcgi_index (defaults to index.php) are in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf`.

That in turn includes `/usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf` which is a list of `fastcgi_param` settings, including the crucial SCRIPT_FILENAME.

Don't ever duplicate `root` in the PHP location block.

Comment: very nice! was that for me! Cheers mate!

Comment: Thanks. For me the fpm/nginx docker containers I was running had permission issues accessing these folders.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder's answer is **wrong** and yours is right! In my case it was, indeed, **only** a matter of correcting the ownership in the `/etc/php/7.0/php-fpm.d/www.conf` file. Cheers to you, bud. :) Many more people may start to see this issue also as vagrant popularity continues to grow.

Comment: couldn't find anything inside `/usr/local/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` on my mac.. but i did find `/usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf`

Comment: Nice one!! Been struggling for hours

Comment: The walk-through on verifying the script filename by logging it is genius!

Answer (score 10):

**"Primary script unknown"** is caused by **SELinux security context.**

client get the response

> File not found.

nginx error.log has the following error message

> *19 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream

so just change security context type of web root folder to **httpd_sys_content_t**

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/show
```

there are 3 users for nginx/php-fpm config

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user nobody nobody;  ### `user-1`, this is the user run nginx woker process
...
include servers/*.conf;
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/www.conf**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;  # tcp socket
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/fpm-www.sock;  # unix socket
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

**/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf**

```
[www]
user = apache  ### `user-2`, this is the user run php-fpm pool process
group = apache

;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000  # tcp socket
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/fpm-www.sock  # unix socket

listen.onwer = nobody  ### `user-3`, this is the user for unix socket, like /var/run/php-fpm/fpm-www.sock
listen.group = nobody  # for tcp socket, these lines can be commented
listen.mode = 0660
```

**user-1 and user-2 are not necessary to be the same.**

**for unix socket, user-1 need to be the same as user-3,**
as nginx fastcgi_pass must have read/write permission on the unix socket.

otherwise nginx will get **502 Bad Gateway**, and nginx error.log has the following error message

> *36 connect() to unix:/var/run/php-fpm/fpm-www.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream

**and the user/group of web root folder (/var/www/show) is not necessary to be the same as any of these 3 users.**

Answer (score 9):

Had the same problem with a newer nginx (v1.8). Newer versions recommend using `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;` instead of `fastcgi.conf`. So if you copy/pasted `include fastcgi.conf` from a tutorial, you might end up with the `Primary script unknown` error in the log.

Answer (score 4):

I did everything from above, lost 2 hours banging my head and problem still persisted. Finally I did:

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

And viola it worked!

Btw, I was setting up fresh symfony 3.4 project with nginx conf from link:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/web_server_configuration.html

That was my fifth time of begining new symfony project and I couldn't believed this "Primary script unknown" is happening.

Comment: Very underrated answer. I was struggling a day trying almost all suggested solution, and wouldn't believe that just need to restart php to fix the error.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by closing SELINUX in CentOS7.3 system

steps:

- exec `setenforce 0`
- U also need to modify config file

`vim /etc/selinux/config set SELINUX to disabled`

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue also, and I solved it by exchanging the lines `include fastcgi_params` and `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME ...`.

Indeed nginx sets the last value of each FastCGI parameter, so you have to put your value after the default value included in fastcgi_params.

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions for your php-fpm sock file, somehow it wasn't accessable :

`chmod 755 /usr/local/var/run/php-fpm.sock`

then try to restart nginx.

Comment: Also, consider verifying if `php-fpm` user shares `nginx` group. For example, `sudo usermod -a -G www-data php-fpm` if `nginx` runs as `www-data` and `php-fpm` runs as `php-fpm`.

Comment: Do **NOT** use this method, you are basically introducing a security issue here. The command in the answer provide everyone read and write access to the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add root directive within your php location.

```
location ~ \.php {
      root /home/willem/git/console/www;
      ...
}
```

Comment: The `root` directive should be set on a per `server` basis and shouldn't be used within any `location` blocks (unless you're a pro and want to circumvent some very special nginx bugs in your configuration).

Comment: @Fleshgrinder one root per server is not best practice.

Comment: Yeah, sure: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block

Comment: @Fleshgrinder That's not what the section you linked says. The example of good practice in that section shows a `root` directive inside a `location` block.

Comment: @ishigoya please visit the link again, the multiple `root` directives inside multiple `location` blocks is clearly under the BAD heading.

Comment: @Fleshgrinder What the pitfall is pointing out is that there should always be a `root` directive before the `location` blocks, so that no location is lacking a `root`. This is described in the text. It isn't written anywhere that multiple `root` directives can't be used, and it certainly doesn't say that the `root` directive shouldn't be used within any `location` blocks, as your first comment said.

Comment: But @lg is right that you might get this error when the root under the server section is not defined. Was the case in my setting and defining root solved it..

Comment: HOLY FUCK! I WASTED THREE HOURS trying to find the answer and your's is the only one that worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

I found your question looking for the same error message but using apache + php-fpm (no nginx). For me, the problem was a slash in the wrong place: many setup suggestions include a line of the form:

```
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/path/to/file.socket|fcgi://localhost/:9000"
```

By placing the last slash after the port number like so:

```
SetHandler "proxy:unix:/path/to/file.socket|fcgi://localhost:9000/"
```

the problem dissappeared for me. Maybe you can do something similar

Answer (score 0):

I've been trapped by this weird message for a very long time. I'm not sure about the cause because everything worked for a while then all of a sudden stopped working.

I was shortening wiki URLs as prescribed by MediaWiki, with Bitnami / Nginx on Lightsail.

Searched and read many posts, this one seems to summarize all possible scenarios, and I tried them all:

- nginx is fine, root folder php is working, subfolder is not
- error thrown as 404 + a bare string "File not found", not by nginx
- add `root` to server, did not work
- check permissions of folders and php-fpm / nginx, no problem root and subfolders are the same
- check php-fpm manual for error code interpretation, could not find one
- turn on php-fpm access log, found the request URI was correct, but 404 is returned
- try to turn on verbose / debug mode for php-fpm, did not work, the supposed error log file is always empty

So I had to try the last resort, since root folder php was working and subfolders were not, the only major difference between them other than `root` is root folder used `$request_filename` and subfolder locations used `$document_root` and `$fastcgi_script_name`, so I changed subfolder location settings to match root folder ones.

Then it worked...I am still not sure *why* it worked. Because when I check php-fpm access log I see same URI, one was 404 and the other was 200.

[image]

The only difference was in the configuration. Since they produce the same output, I don't know why the result came out differently.

Anyway I decided to post my 2 cents here, hope this helps.

PS: I really do hope PHP provide better error messages and verbose mode, because this is really frustrating not being able to isolate the problem and no way to see verbose output and debug info.

Answer (score 0):

To me it was extensions.

My `php-fpm.www.access.log` was reporting:

```
"GET /index.php5" 404
```

Yet the index file for the site (MediaWiki) was `index.php`. Turns out i had mixed extensions (`php` vs `php5`) in the relevant `nginx.conf` entries. Here's a working config:

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ = @mediawiki;
}
location = /favicon.ico {
    return 204;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/viki$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /path/to/viki;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}

location @mediawiki {
    rewrite ^/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /index.php?title=$1&$args last;
}
```

You can have all these entries use `index.php5` instead, just add a `index.php5` file to the root with this content:

```
<?php require './index.php';
```

(no closing tag).

Answer (score 0):

Annother reason can be a missing semicolon (;) after the server_name

```
server_name domainurl.com
root /var/www/current/public;
```

which leads to a warning but no error!

Answer (score -1):

> I  meet the same question, But Other method didn't help me resolve the
>   question!
>
> I  resolve it, I find the key is that:  **Linux User Right lead to the
>   question:   FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"**
>
> Because The PHP-FPM default user:group is  apache:apache,  But your
>   code dir is someBody:someBody. So you should change the User right!
>
> I write a blog to resolve this question, You can see this blog:
>
> [Nginx FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"][1] `   [1]:
>   http://geekhades.blogspot.com/2017/06/nginx-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-primary.html

Answer (score -1):

I cloned a remote site, and the already existing wp-config.php had the remote server database info.

I resolved this issue by setting up my local wordpress config, with my local database info.